# Migration of huge quantities of data to SQL

Tags: sql-server, timeout, migration, wmi, cluster-computing

I need to migrate extremely large quantities of data (millions of files, Terabytes of data) to an SQL cluster. The migration process is partitioned into weekly migrations, with a few hundreds of new users (i.e request-generators) every week.

So far things have run pretty smoothly, but lately i've discovered that the SQL cluster started to act quite strangely. The CPU usage is sound and stable at about 20%, but the SQL-process is constantly allocating new memory until there is nothing left (about 12GB). When this happens the process "dumps" all memory and starts climbing towards 12GB anew. During this dump, it is often the case that the server gets unresponsive and eventually timeouts, which just cannot happen during this weeks migration.

Is this allocate-and-dump behaviour common for SQL clusters? Is it possible to make configurations to it so this will never happen, or at least not congest the whole database? Does anyone have experience with large migration jobs?

When looking through the event logs i found some WMI-warning preceeding the timout. We're using System Center Operations Manager 2007 to overlook the system, could this explain this behaviour?

Thankful for any help!

Comment: Are you sure the services are not re-starting or rolling over from one node to another? How are you getting the data into SQL? Are you using BCP or standard INSERTS?

Comment: If you think the WMI warning is important enough to mention in your question, you should actually include it as well. (You can edit your question, please do not post it to the answers section.)

Comment: What are the WMI errors?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not normal behaviour.

SQL Server will dynamically allocate memory as required and will free memory appropriately when under pressure to do so. It should not however dump the entire contents.

Can you please provide more details about your environment and qualify what your SQL memory configuration is.

If you require detailed assistance, feel free to drop me an email and please provide the results of the DBCC command.

```
DBCC memorystatus
```